# Youtube API Content Owner Error

Tags: youtube-api

I am having an issue while making a call to https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/claimSearch through a script. Following is the partial response that suggests the failure due to lack of Content Owner. We have multiple accounts attached to one email and I tried sending the email address as well as the one of the account as content owner but still getting the same error.

```
'_msg' => 'Bad Request',
'_request' => bless( {
'_content' => '',
'_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o ='https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/claimSearch')}, 'URI::https' ),
'_headers' => bless( {
'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/6.03',
'videoid' => 'MjMpgVRZjqU', 
'contentowner' => 'tunesat_music_label',
'onbehalfofcontentowner' => '5qo5EmXXXXXX',
'authorization' => 'Bearer ya29.qwHkgGH2obX6GOS7oNItTlVSN822K4hKxhNSjZQCWyo2vp1zPvYGMzivKf7XZA_5Ath0UqjvAqZRqA',
'key' => 'AIzaSyBCXXXXXX'
}, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
'_method' => 'GET',
'_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri'}
}, 'HTTP::Request' )




"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "youtubePartner",
"reason": "contentOwnerNotProvided",
"message": "Content owner was not provided. If you manage multiple content     owner accounts, you must specify one content owner in each request."
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "Content owner was not provided. If you manage multiple content owner accounts, you must specify one content owner in each request."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A content owner is a YouTube partner who has the rights to a collection of assets. Content ID API is not available to everyone to use. It's only meant to be used for YouTube Partners. https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/identify_content_owner

> Note: The YouTube Content ID API is intended for use by YouTube
>   content partners and is not accessible to all developers or to all
>   YouTube users. If you do not see the YouTube Content ID API as one of
>   the services listed in the Google Developers Console, see
>   www.youtube.com/partner to learn more about the YouTube Partner
>   Program.

Comment: I had already added the YouTube Content ID API to our corporate account before posting my question.